# Migrated from Glide 3 to 4 and having a AbstractMethodError when launching the app

Tags: android-glide

I have an application using Glide 3.8.0 and I've just migrated it to 4.8.0. After migrating all the code to use the new Glide's API, I've found that my app launches this error when trying to load an image from the network:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.bumptech.glide.module.RegistersComponents.registerComponents(android.content.Context, com.bumptech.glide.Glide, com.bumptech.glide.Registry)"
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:268)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:221)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:182)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:166)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:680)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:732)
        at com.fewlaps.android.quitnow.usecase.main.MainActivity.updateAvatar(MainActivity.java:356)
        etc...
```

I've done the setup [explained in the official documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html). As it requests, I wrote a class that extends `AppGlideModule`, it's annotated by `@GlideModule`, and it's empty. Empty? The official documentation says:

*You’re not required to implement any of the methods in AppGlideModule for the API to be generated. You can leave the class blank as long as it extends AppGlideModule and is annotated with @GlideModule.*

According to the `Error`'s message, my issue is related with `registerComponents()` for sure, but I also tried to implement it with a blank implementation, and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in `AppGlideModule`'s JavaDoc (and as far as I know, only there...), if you are done with the migration from 3.x.x to 4.x.x, you have to implement `isManifestParsingEnabled()` returning `false`.

So, you'll end with a `CustomAppGlideModule` like this one:

```
@GlideModule
public class QNGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```